# Vim - Command Line - previous and next command key mapping

Tags: vim, command, mapping, line

When opening the command line and pressing the up arrow or down arrow keys, it shows the commands there were typed the last time. Is there a way to map this behaviour? For example when I press `ctrl p`, I want vim to show me my previous command (make vim act as if I pressed the up arrow). The same thing for `ctrl n` for the next command.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: It works out of the box, just press `:` and then navigate to previous with `Ctrl + p`

Comment: Lol, literally exactly what I needed and it was there the whole time. Thank you!

Comment: There's a small difference between CTRL-P and Up arrow, in that Up arrow will only expand matches which start with the characters you typed.

Comment: Oh, I see, is there a way to make ctrl-p behave the same as up arrow?

Comment: @DasOhmoffSan Revived and expanded my answer to cover that. I hope that's helpful! Let me know if any of the points is not fully clear to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `CTRL-P` and `CTRL-N` keystrokes *already* do what you want, they search your command history. See [`:help c_CTRL-P`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-P), which explains how it will "recall older command-line from history."

The way `CTRL-P` and `CTRL-N` work differs slightly from the up and down arrow, in that the arrows will only go through the items in history that start with the characters you typed. So `:e`, space, up arrow will go to the last command you used to open a file for editing. See [`:help c_<Up>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_%3CUp%3E) for details.

You can remap them so that they do the same as their counterpart, by using the `cnoremap` command, which creates mappings for keystrokes typed while in the Vim command-line.

For example, to make `CTRL-P` and `CTRL-N` behave the same as the arrows (complete respecting the prefix), you can use the following commands to create a (somewhat naive) mapping:

```
cnoremap <C-P> <Up>
cnoremap <C-N> <Down>
```

The shortcoming of this approach is that `CTRL-P` and `CTRL-N` behave differently on a wildmenu, so a more complete mapping would be:

```
cnoremap <expr> <C-P> wildmenumode() ? "\<C-P>" : "\<Up>"
cnoremap <expr> <C-N> wildmenumode() ? "\<C-N>" : "\<Down>"
```

That will preserve the original behavior of `CTRL-P` and `CTRL-N` in the wildmenu.